# Remove a file from the compile, mark it as text

Tags: android-studio

Today's Android Studio Tip of the Day...
You can exclude any file from your project. As a result, such a file will be ignored by indexing, inspection and code completion.
In the **Project tool window, select the file you want to ignore, and choose Mark as plain text in its context menu.**
If necessary, you can always return the file to its original type using the Mark as  context menu command.

If this means View >> Tool Windows >> Project  I could not find this useful functionality. Any pointers??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's in View → Tool Windows → Project. But not every file has this option. XML-files do, Java-files do not. The option is right under "Delete...".

[image: Mark as plain text]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I often have java files I'd like to "comment out" while I try something without endangering my basic app. Do you happen to know why this does not work for .java files.

Comment: No, i've got no idea :(

Comment: In case of java file I should rename it as .txt  )

Comment: I have marked my Kotlin files as plain text, but they are still triggering compile time errors